# How to run selenium webdriver on client machine?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-8

I have implemented selenium web-driver with IE in a java web application.
I am using Apache tomcat 6 to run the application.
All the tests are running fine on local machine,but when i am trying to access it with other machine its opening the browser in the server machine and performing the tests.
My requirement is when any client access my application, the tests should run on the client machine, i mean browser should open on the client machine and do the tests.

my current selenium set up

```
File file = new File("C:/Jar File/IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
    caps.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
```

Any help will be appreciated, plz let me know if i am not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using selenium grid, use `RemoteWebDriver` instead of `InternetExplorerDriver`.

> RemoteWebDriver: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver
>
> Selenium Grid: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2

If you already registered a node on your hub, which has a registered Internet Explorer, then you can start your tests on it, if you init your WebDriver like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
dc.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
dc.setVersion("any");

WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://HUB_IP:HUB_PORT/wd/hub), dc);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, But how can i open internet explorer on client side..because i want to use IE to test.

Comment: I tried your code,i have created hub and register the node and after that when i am accessing the URL the browser is opening on the server...I am using tomcat apache server to run my java web application...my selenium test code is integrated in the application and executes on specific events...